# How to Gzip a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, webserver, gzip

179KB of jQuery is Minified and Gzipped to 26KB. I am trying to do the same compressions to my javascript files and found the Yuicompressor to Minify it. But I am still searching for a way to Gzip it.

How can I Gzip my Javascript files?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using it in a webpage, gzip is a configuration method in your web server. The file is gzipped by the server, sent to the browser. No manual action is needed. For Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html.

If you are delivering the code to developers, you could use the `gzip` command.

Comment: Thanks, if you know about the Gzip configuration on Glassfish 3.0.1 server please give me some guidance.

Comment: Try using http://www.zbugs.com - just provide your website url and it will do everything for you.

Answer (score 9):

You would use `gzip`, the GNU compression utility. Luckily, the gzip algorithm and file structure is implemented by numerous other tools, such as 7zip (for Windows).  You can configure your server (via `mod_deflate` or others) to compress files on the fly, but for static content its a waste of CPU power.

Here is an article which shows how to transparently serve pre-compressed gzip to browsers which support it: https://typeoverflow.com/typeoverflow/serve-pre-compressed-gzip-javascript-to-browsers-4k6j

Comment: It would be wise to employ content negotiation instead of mod_rewrite clumsiness

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [zbugs.com](http://www.zbugs.com) - just provide your website url and it will do everything for you.